# Modifying private members of a class

Tags: class, c++11, private

I'm having a few issues changing a private member of a class. 
below is my main.cpp

```
#include "World.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//function prototypes
void setUserName();


int main()
{
    setUserName();
    return 0;
}
```

below is my GameObject.h

```
#ifndef GAMEOBJECT_H
#define GAMEOBJECT_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class GameObject
{
private:
    string userName;

public:
    void setUserName();
};

#endif
```

below is my gameobject.cpp

```
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void setUserName()
{
    cout << endl << "Function has been called" << endl;
    cin >> userName;
}
```

It's currently telling me userName was not declared in this scope, but I thought I declared in my .h file
Any tips would be great appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The global function

```
void setUserName();
```

and the member function with the same name declared inside `class GameObject` are two different functions.  Only the member function has access to the private member.  If you want to define the member function in gameobject.cpp, you need to give the full function name:

```
void GameObject::setUserName {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You implemented a function and named it `setUserName()` and you declared a method of class `GameObject` and named it also `setUserName()`. Only the method is able to access the private variable. But for the method there is no implementation.

The method implementation (in gameobject.cpp) would look like:

```
void GameObject::setUserName()
{
    cout << endl << "Function has been called" << endl;
    cin >> userName;
}
```

For your purpose I think you even don't need the global function `setUserName()` at all.